# TSQL question : how to iterate columns of result set

Tags: t-sql

I have a select statement and a cursor to iterate the rows I get. the problem is that I have many columns (more than 500),  and so "fetch .. into @variable" is impossible for me. how can I iterate the columns (one by one, I need to process the data)?

Thanks in advance,
n.b

Answer (score 1):

Two choices.

1/ Use SSIS or ADO.Net to pour through your dataset row by row.
2/ Consider what you're actually needing to achieve and find a set-based approach.

My preference is for option 2. Let us know what you need done and we'll find a way.

Rob

Comment: That what I did .. I have one table which get the data from a flat file using SSIS. now I need to process the data (validation, matching etc.) and iterating the columns seems necessary for it.

n.b

Comment: nab, you never need to iterate to do validation or matching. In fact you almost never need to iterate to do anything. I fyou are using a cursor, that is your first clue to look for a better way to do things.  I import data all the time and do all data cleanup with set-based code which is usually much faster than iteration. Or you can do all the data validation in your SSIS package.

Comment: nab - you'd've been better off putting the validation in the SSIS package. Then you can send the unvalidated data off to a different table, or through a set of cleansing processes, while the clean data ends up in your table. Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can build a SQL string using [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) or [INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx). [Here's a post I wrote on that](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2003/12/11/43043.aspx).